# Have or to have?

Tags: prepositions

I am reading this piece off some rules to open an account.
"Brokers are mandated by law to require day traders have $3,000 in their accounts at all times"
Why not "Brokers are mandated by law to require day traders ***to*** have $3,000 in their accounts at all times"

Comment: The sentence would read better with **...to require that day traders have..** or as you suggest. But financial institutions do not always concern themselves with the niceties of English.

Comment: require someone have something is perfectly good English: We require parents bring their children early.

Comment: Thanks folks. A bit of what I was thinking. Added some awareness to my English skills too. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to correct this as written would be:

> Brokers are mandated by law to require **that** day traders have
>   $3,000 in their accounts at all times.

The example you provided is another acceptable alternative:

> Brokers are mandated by law to require day traders **to** have $3,000
>   in their accounts at all times.

While it might be technically permissible as written, I disagree that it's "perfectly good English."

IMHO, the best way to write this would be to eliminate the passive voice:

> The law requires that day traders have $3,000 in their accounts at all
>   times.

or

> The law requires day traders to have $3,000 in their accounts at all
>   times.